# Efficient way of rank update based on points

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

User_team=User_team.objects.filter().values(),

User_team=[{team_id:1, points:50},{team_id:2, points:30},{team_id:3, points:70}]

I already migrate New model and key is (rank,point) stored rank and points in this model.

User_team_event=User_team_event.objects.filter().values().
I'm expecting answer is without using loops:

User_team_event=[{team_id:3,rank:1, points:70},{team_id:1,rank:2, points:50},{team_id:2, points:30}]

Answer (score 0):

Please *don't* store the rank in a model, and if the points are aggregates, don't store these in the model either: things that can be determined (easily) should not be stored explicitly, this is *data duplication* which is an anti-pattern: it turns out that keeping duplicated data in sync is a complicated problem that nearly always eventually goes wrong.

Ranks can easily be determined when *needed*, not by storing this in the model. Indeed, if you want to know the rank of a certain object, you can query it with:

```
class UserTeam(models.Model):
    points = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def rank(self):
        rank = getattr(self, '_rank', None)
        if rank is None:
            rank = self._rank = (
                UserTeam.objects.filter(points__gt=self.points).count() + 1
            )
        return rank
```

We thus determine the number of `UserTeam`s with a higher number of points, and that is our rank.

If you want to annotate these in bulk, you can use a [**`Window`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.Window):

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.expressions import Window
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber

userteam = UserTeam.annotate(
    _rank=Window(expression=RowNumber(), order_by=[F('points').desc()]) + 1
).order_by('-points')
```

this will then calculate the ranks all in bulk, so the `rank` property will not have to calculate these itself.

Comment: Ok thanks..but two objects same points, how it works??

Comment: @Muthumani18: they share the rank, so it is 1224 ranking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Standard_competition_ranking_(%221224%22_ranking)